# objects being lost

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

In my angular app I'm trying to save/retrieve data between pages and have have the following function in place:

```
$scope.storeData = function () {

    var selections = $scope.devices;
    console.log(selections);

    sessionStorage.setItem('selectedHandsets', JSON.stringify(selections));

    var ss = sessionStorage.getItem('selectedHandsets');
    console.log(ss);

}
```

The issue is quite strange. The key values that I'm after in `selections` are 'selectedManufacturer' and 'selectedModel' and these values are displaying as expected in `console.log(selections)`.

When `ss` is logged, 'selectedManufacturer' and 'selectedModel' aren't visible in `sessionStorage.selectedHandsets`. They're there when the data is being set because we can see it in selections but when I log `ss`, they're gone!

The format of `selections` is like so:

```
[
    [
        { ... },
        { ... },
        selectedModel: { ... },
        selectedManufacuterer: { ... }
    ],
    [
        { ... },
        { ... },
        selectedModel: { ... },
        selectedManufacuterer: { ... }
    ]
]
```

If I wrap `JSON.stringify()` around `console.log(selections)` then selectedModel and selectedManufacturer are disappearing. Could somebody explain to me exactly why this is happening and what the appropriate fix is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried checking the console if it throws an error?

What you have is a malformed JSON

```
[
    [
        { ... },
        { ... },
        selectedModel: { ... },
        selectedManufacuterer: { ... }
    ],
    [
        { ... },
        { ... },
        selectedModel: { ... },
        selectedManufacuterer: { ... }
    ]
]
```

Look at

```
    [
        { ... },
        { ... },
        selectedModel: { ... }, //There shouldn't be a named item in an array here
        selectedManufacuterer: { ... } //There shouldn't be a named item in an array here
    ]
```

There shouldn't be a named object in an array.

---

EDITS

What you did was like this:

```
var arrayBuff= [];
arrayBuff.push(2);
arrayBuff.push(4);
arrayBuff.push(6);

//this would produce this: [2,4,6]
console.log(arrayBuff);

arrayBuff.someField = "foobar";

//this would produce this: [2,4,6, someField: "foobar"]
// which is a malformed array
console.log(arrayBuff);
```

You can do this instead:

```
var arrayBuff = {},
    arrayBuff.arrays = [];
arrayBuff.arrays.push(2);
arrayBuff.arrays.push(4);
arrayBuff.arrays.push(6);

//this would produce this: { arrays: [2,4,6] }
console.log(arrayBuff);

arrayBuff.someField = "foobar";

//this would produce this: { arrays: [2,4,6], someField: "foobar"}
// which is correct and can be parsed by JSON.stringify
console.log(arrayBuff);
```

The reason why the JSON.stringify wasn't been able to parsed the named field was, simply because it was expecting an array.

Comment: How do I fix this? Angular is pushing in the named item (which is what I'm needing) as they're the values of ng-models

Comment: can you provide the JSON.stringify raw result before putting it in the localstorage? the string form of selections. from there, we can see what happened

Comment: no errors, it just ignores the named objects and doesn't include them

Comment: what browser where you testing at? I'm really baffled by the result. It never throws an error while processing a malformed structure.

Comment: Using chrome and the inspection tools

Comment: what would be the best way to deconstruct the invalid array by pulling out selectedModel and selectedManufacturer, storing in subarray and then restoring in the new pages where the data is needed again?

Comment: We can arrive with a solution if you can provide a snippet, on a jsfiddle would be best on how you include values on selections. If you're using a third-party directive, what  was it? I can help you in debugging this. Or, the other way is your can recode the way you construct selection. Put it in a way you're creating an array of objects and not the current one.

Comment: nevermind, I have recreated how you managed to come up with that result. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I came up with my own solution by picking out selectedmodel and selectedmanufacturer from each array inside $scope.devices, push these into their own arrays and then save these into localstorage. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is right. What you can do is reconstruct your selections to be an object like 
{ arrObjs : [ your array will be here], models: [...], manufacturers:[...] }